# Size of all files whose path fulfils condition

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, size

I would like to calculate the total size of all files in a given directory that fulfil the condition:

- The path of the file (or, equally good, the directory of the file) contains the string `DEV_`

The operating system is Windows Server 2012.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to google this, but was not able to find an approach. I thought about coding the whole thing in Java (which is not very hard), but hoped that one can do it more directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PowerShell while this folder is the current:

```
Get-ChildItem * -Filter *DEV_* | Measure-Object -Sum Length
```